# tf.data.Dataset with constant size batches

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with 19 elements and a batch size of 10. I set my dataset to continuously iterate over the same elements but I noticed that the last batch has only 4 elements instead of 5, and then it starts over with 5, 5, 5, 4, and so on.

How is is possible to force the iterator to fill up shorter batches with elements coming from the next iteration so that all the batches have the same size?

P.S. just to understand, isn't this the obvious behavior when training a model?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of [`tf.data.Dataset.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch), there is an optional `drop_remainder` parameter to discard the last incomplete batch. I don't know if there is a way to complete the last batch with the beginning of the next iteration. If you're shuffling your data it shouldn't matter discarding the last batch, but anyway it would be interesting to have a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have this behavior, the `.repeat()` method should be invoked before the `batch()` or `padded_batch()` one. So:

```
file_names = [...]
def my_map_func(record):
    ....
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_names)\
    .map(map_func=my_map_func)\
    .repeat()\  # here!
    .batch(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the use of `repeat` and `batch` I will say this. Actually the place where you put the `.repeat()` does not matter much if you want to have a fixed batch_size. If you set set `drop_remainder=True` in `.batch()` you won't get `None` in the first dimension, you will get a fixed batch size no matter it the position of `.repeat()`. Repeat and batch is very intuitively to use, for example, let's define 4 data-sets varying the position of batch and repeat:

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)

dataset1 = dataset.batch(2,drop_remainder=True)
dataset1 = dataset1.repeat()

dataset2 = dataset.repeat()
dataset2 = dataset2.batch(2,drop_remainder=True)

dataset3 = dataset.repeat()
dataset3 = dataset3.batch(2)

dataset4 = dataset.batch(2)
dataset4 = dataset4.repeat()
```

you will get this as result:

**Dataset1**: Notice how 2 is never in any batch

- shape: (2,): Notice that the batch size is 2 and not None
- batch 1: [0,1]
- batch 1: [0,1]

**Dataset2**: This is what you want to do to achieve what you want. Notice how now 2 is in the second batch

- shape: (2,): Again, the batch size is not None and the position of `repeat` is different
- batch 1: [0,1]
- batch 1: [2,0]

**Dataset3**:

- shape: (?,): Because you are not using `drop_remainder=True` you get a None, nonetheless you will get batches **always** of fix size 2. This will happen no matter how many times you repeat it
- batch 1: [0,1]
- batch 2: [2,0]
- batch 3: [1,2]

**Dataset4**:

- shape(?,): Same a as Dataset3
- batch 1: [0,1]
- batch 2: [2] you get 'incomplete' batch sizes
- batch 3: [0,1]